# Properly handling timing for HTML5 canvas engine

Tags: javascript, canvas, simulation, game-physics, timing

I'm working on a multiple projectile simulator for a college project and I'm wondering how to best setup timing in JavaScript rendering to a HTML5 canvas

I'm using an Euler integrator setup for physics and accuracy is very important for this project. The rendering is very bare bones

My question is how to best setup the timing for all this.

Right now I have:

- The physics and other logic running in a function that loops using setTimeout() with a fixed time step
- The rendering in another function that loops using a requestAnimationFrame() call (flexible time step)

These two loops run sort of simultaneously (I know JavaScript doesn't really support threads without Web Workers) but I don't want the rendering (currently running at a much higher FPS than needed) to be unnecessarily 'stealing' CPU cycles from the physics simulation, if you see what I mean.

Given that physics accuracy is most important here how would you recommend setting up the timing system? (Maybe using Web Workers would be useful here but I havent seen this used in other engines)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you don't try to 'multithread' unless you're actually doing it, and even then, I wouldn't necessarily recommend it.

The best way to keep everything in synch is to have a single thread of execution. A single `setTimeout` loop of about `33`ms seems to work ok for my games.

Also, in my experience at least, `setTimeout` offers a much more aesthetic experience than `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`. With `setInterval`, Javascript tries to hard to 'catch up' when frames are delivered late, which makes animation frames inconsistent. With `requestAnimationFrame`, frames are skipped to ensure a smooth running game, which actually makes things harder, because your users aren't entirely sure their view is up to date at any given second.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to set an interval for processing physics, and once per x frames, render everything.

```
var physicsTime;
var renderFrequency;
var frameCount;

setInterval(function(){updateStuff()},physicsTime);
```

then in updateStuff()

```
function updateStuff(){
  frameCount ++;
  if (frameCount >= renderFrequency){
    frameCount -= renderFrequency;
    render();
  }
  physics();
}
```